# Regex of a string

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to match a certain string. At the moment I have this regex:

```
regx = /wid=\d+(\.\d)*/g,
```

which would match `wid=100` in the following link/string:

```
image/hugoboss/test%2Dimg?wid=100
```

However I want to extend this link/string to :

```
image/hugoboss/test%2Dimg?wid=100&crop=0,0,960,650
```

so that it ends with this format `&crop=0,0,960,650`. How could I adapt my regex so that it matches `wid=100&crop=0,0,960,650`

Thanks!

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: are you interested in query string only from URL?

Comment: What's your intent? Simply to get key=value pairs from the URL! or to make certain key=value pairs required?

Comment: Are you confused? Share more info. What do you think?

Comment: In which case while you mention using regular expressions that's a fragile means to solve a solved problem. Although if you *must* use regex (please don't, it really is fraught with edge-cases) this answer might be of more use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below regex,

```
wid=\d+(\.\d)*(?:&crop=\d+(?:,\d+)*)?
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pW2tP5/2)

OR

the below regex would allow floating point numbers after the string `crop`

```
wid=\d+(\.\d)*(?:&crop=\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:,\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pW2tP5/3)

```
> "image/hugoboss/test%2Dimg?wid=100&crop=0,0,960,650".match(/wid=\d+(\.\d)*(?:&crop=\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:,\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*)/g);
[ 'wid=100&crop=0,0,960,650' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the matched group from index 1

```
\?(.*)$
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/kR1eR4/5)

The regex looks for everything after `?` till end to the string/line.

Sample code:

```
var str="image/hugoboss/test%2Dimg?wid=100&crop=0,0,960,650";
var re = /\?(.*)$/; 
console.log(str.match(re)[1]);
```

output:

```
wid=100&crop=0,0,960,650
```

Comment: I think you should use `/(wid.*)$/`, as per the question.