# Regext to match part of a string

Tags: jquery, regex

I have the following code. I would like to adapt the current regex  `/wid=\d+(\.\d)*/g` so that it matches `wid=100&crop=0,0,960,650` and not just `wid=100`. How can I adapt it to do this?

HTML

```
<img class="image-resize" src="http://hugoboss.scene7.com/is/image/hugoboss/test%2Dimg?wid=100&crop=0,0,960,650" name="mainimg" id="mainimg"/>
```

JQUERY

```
 var regx = /wid=\d+(\.\d)*/g;
    currentWidth = src.match(regx);
    newWidth = 'wid=960&crop=0,0,960,650';
    newSrc = src.replace(currentWidth, newWidth);
```

Comment: What about your [last post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367604/regex-of-a-string/25367674#25367652) that is exactly same. Share your views with guys who answered to make it clear.

Comment: You have commented nothing on answers of your last post. Why?

Comment: If your question is closed as a duplicate look at the answers to that question! If they don't pertain to your question then post on comment on your original question, do not repost your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex.

```
wid=.*?(?=")
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/oS3cI4/1)**

[image]

As **[skamazin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3748504/skamazin)** pointed in the comment you could achieve the same by using below regex (it could improve the readability):

```
wid=.*?"
```

Comment: I don't think you need that look-ahead.

Comment: @skamazin it's an option. I used it to get all the content until the quote. If I removed my regex doesn't work.

Comment: As far as I can tell, [this](http://regex101.com/r/oS3cI4/2) is exactly the same and more readable. Perhaps my first comment wasn't clear; I meant you need the double quote but not inside a look-ahead

Comment: @skamazin I see your point. Yup, you are right. I'll update my answer pointing that. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

How about this version: `wid.*\d`

http://regex101.com/r/rI7tE0/1

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var regx = /wid=[^"]+/;
```